# Help me understand this problem please

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics, matrix-exponential

As you can see in equation 15.19, the authors of the book replaced $ (-a R_t +1) $ with the $ \exp(h)$ with $h =2.5$.
Can you help me understand how the authors got this value? I searched the whole chapter and couldn't find an answer.

[image]

Comment: If $aR_t$ was small $h=2$ would be more reasonable since $\mathrm{e}^{-x}\approx 1-x$ for small $x$. By the way, the author replaces $1-aR_t$ by $\mathrm{e}^{-1.5aR_t}$ and not by $\mathrm{e}^h$. Which book is this?

Comment: What is the equation 15.8?

Comment: The equation 15.8 is marginal profit, assuming constant marginal costs. So basically the equation 15.8 describes a rent. This book is Natural Resource and Environmental Economics (by Roger Perman Yue Ma James McGilvray Michael Common) 3rd edition. This is a part of a model to determine the optimal quantity extraction of a non-renewable resource.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's pages 535-536

Comment: @Meg I have no access to this book.

Comment: @gary do you think there is an analytical solution for $R_t$ to $ (1-aR_t).e^{-aR} = e^{i(t-T)} $

Comment: The Lambert $W$-function can be useful.